# list of removed outliers from dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use this code to remove outliers from my df

```
from scipy import stats
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

how do I get a list of all the rows index I deleted? thanks!

Comment: invert the condition `np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) >= 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in obtaining the index of the deleted rows:

```
index = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) >= 3).all(axis=1)].index
```

Answer (score 0):

```
index = list(df.index.values)
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
removed_index = []
index_after_remove = list(df.index.values)
for i in index:
    if i not in index_after_remove:
        removed_index.append(i)
```